# Zend Framework 2 using Navigation use_route_match option with optional params

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am having problems on using the use_route_match feature, i want to see only some of the params instead of all in the generated url, is it possible to setup a conf as i tried to do below? Or What do you suggest?

My global.php

```
return array(
    'navigation'      => array(
    'default'    => array(
            array(  
                'route'           => 'home',
                'label'           => 'Anasayfa',
                'resource'        => 'Application\Controller\Index\index',
                'use_route_match' => true
            )
        )
    )
);
```

how can i use "use_route_match" only my optional params ?

for example

```
return array(
    'navigation'      => array(
    'default'    => array(
            array(  
                'route'                    => 'home',
                'label'                    => 'Anasayfa',
                'resource'                 => 'Application\Controller\Index\index',
                'use_route_match'          => true,
                'use_route_match_myparams' => array('lang', 'param1', 'param2')
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: try 'params' => array('key' => 'value'),

Comment: i don't want. i want to see only some of the params instead of all in the generated url, is it possible to setup a conf as i tried to do below

Answer (score 0):

you have route like this

```
'home' => array(
    'type'    => 'Literal',
    'options' => array(
        'route'    => '/home[/:lang][/:param1][/:param2]',
        'constraints' => array(
          'id' => '[0-9]+',
        ),
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
            'action'     => 'index',
        ),
     ),
 ),
```

and your navigation

```
return array(
    'navigation'      => array(
    'default'    => array(
            array(  
                'route'                    => 'home',
                'label'                    => 'Anasayfa',
                'resource'                 => 'Application\Controller\Index\index',
                'use_route_match'          => true,
                'params' => array('lang' => 'en', 'param1' => 'param1')
            )
        )
    )
);
```

there is no param2 here